# cython prange - dealing with __Pyx_ErrFetchWithState / __Pyx_ErrRestoreWithState

Tags: python, multithreading, cython

I am using `prange` in order to modify an array. I try to have as few yellow lines as possible in the HTML page generated by the cython compiler with:

```
cython function_prange.pyx -a
```

But when extracting a part of an array to modify it, I always have this kind of code which is generated:

```
{
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    PyGILState_STATE __pyx_gilstate_save = PyGILState_Ensure();
    #endif
    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp flush(__pyx_parallel_exc_type)
    #endif /* _OPENMP */
    if (!__pyx_parallel_exc_type) {
      __Pyx_ErrFetchWithState(&__pyx_parallel_exc_type, &__pyx_parallel_exc_value, &__pyx_parallel_exc_tb);
      __pyx_parallel_filename = __pyx_filename; __pyx_parallel_lineno = __pyx_lineno; __pyx_parallel_clineno = __pyx_clineno;
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_parallel_exc_type);
    }
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
    PyGILState_Release(__pyx_gilstate_save);
    #endif
}
```

Is it possible to avoid these `__Pyx_ErrFetchWithState` / `__Pyx_ErrRestoreWithState`? Does it really matter?

Here is the code that I am using:

A first function adding a double to the diagonal of a matrix contained in an array of size one in **function_nogil.pyx**

```
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
cdef void add_diag(double [:,:,:] a, int a_len, int a_wid, double coeff) nogil:
    cdef int x_max = a_len

    cdef int x
    for x in xrange(x_max):
        a[0,x,x] = a[0,x,x] + coeff
```

Its header in **function_nogil.pxd**

```
cdef void add_diag(double [:,:,:] a, int a_len, int a_wid, double coeff) nogil
```

The function using `prange` in **function_prange.pyx**

```
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
def prange_loop_idx(double [:,:,:] a, int a_dim1, int a_dim2, int a_dim3, double coeff,int num_threads):

    cdef int i = 0

    with nogil,parallel(num_threads=num_threads):
        for i in prange(a_dim1):
            add_diag(a[i:i+1:,],a_dim2,a_dim3,coeff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as bad as it looks. When you look at the full C code you'll see that this is just an error handling bit of code and is only be executed by jumping to it with `goto` following an error condition.

(The error condition is that it checks that the memoryview slice is constructed correctly - I think this is a consequence of using a slice rather than a single index. Things like setting the step to 0 will trigger an error here).

So you have a little bit of extra error checking that probably isn't strictly necessary but I think would be wise to leave alone (on my PC it's this line):

```
if (unlikely(__pyx_memoryview_slice_memviewslice(
   &__pyx_t_4,
    __pyx_v_a.shape[0], __pyx_v_a.strides[0], __pyx_v_a.suboffsets[0],
    0,
    0,
    &__pyx_t_5,
    __pyx_v_i,
    (__pyx_v_i + 1),
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    1) < 0))
{
    __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L12_error)
}
```

but the actual code you're worried about is not called in normal operation, so has almost no cost and you can ignore.

---

I think the code generated by `parallel` and `prange` is probably sufficiently complex that the generated html files aren't 100% useful at showing you the correct bits, and this is why you're seeing it linked to that line, but you're not seeing the error checking code I've shown above.